# Can Java LinkedList be read in multiple-threads safely?

Tags: java

I would like multiple threads to iterate through the elements in a LinkedList. I do not need to write into the LinkedList. Is it safe to do so? Or do I need a synchronized list to make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: if you are just going to do a read then it is threadsafe.

Comment: If it's an immutable LinkedList you're guaranteed to be safe.

Comment: Ummm ... I don't think there is such a thing as an immutable LinkedList.  Any instance of the LinkedList class (not a subclass) is inherently modifiable.  You are not even safe with (just) a guarantee that the list is not changed ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They can do this safely, PROVIDED THAT:

- they synchronize with (all of) the threads that have written the list BEFORE they start the iterations, and
- no threads modify the list during the iterations.

---

The first point is necessary, because unless there is proper synchronization before you start, there is a possibility that one of the "writing" threads has unflushed changes for the list data structures in local cache memory or registers, or one of the reading threads has stale list state in its cache or registers.

(This is one of those cases where a solid understanding of the Java memory model is needed to know whether the scenario is truly thread-safe.)

---

> Or do I need a synchronized list to make it work

You don't necessarily need to go that far.  All you need to do is to ensure that there is a "happens-before" relationship at the appropriate point, and there are a variety of ways to achieve that.  For instance, if the list is created and written by the writer thread, and the writer then passes the list to the reader thread objects before calling `start()` on them.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the point about requiring the fence before the iterations. It seems like it would be one of those "one in a million" bugs, but those suckers can really cause a bad day.

Comment: @pst - yea, it is one of those "one in a million" bugs.  But it is also more likely to happen on multi-core system under real load; i.e. in production!

Comment: What is sufficient synchronization? Imagine a case that I have main thread which initialize the linkedList (then no thread will modify the linkedList since) and then main thread will spawn all the reader threads (calling thread.start) of all threads which will only read the linkedList. Is it sufficient "synchronization" when I'm sure that threads to read are created later? Or do I need to call some magic method (in such case what is it name?) so Java would flush it's internal caches?

Comment: @VitBernatik - Please ask this in a separate Question.  (And provide example code so that we can be sure we understand what you are asking.)

Comment: So I've asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015946/is-it-safe-in-java-to-read-not-modify-objects-which-are-not-thread-safe-like

Answer (score -1):

From the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.

In other words, if you are truly **just** iterating through then you're alright, just be careful.