# Is it safe in Java to read (not modify) objects which are not thread safe (like linked list) from multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

there was already a [question whether threads can simultaneously safely read/iterate LinkeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659977/can-java-linkedlist-be-read-in-multiple-threads-safely/11660017?noredirect=1#comment46230167_11660017). It seems the answer is yes as far as no-one structurally changes it (add/delete) from the linked list.

Although one answer was warning about "unflushed cache" and advicing to know "java memory model". So I'm asking to elaborate those "evil" caches. I'm a newbie and so far I still naively believe that following code is ok (at least from my tests)

```
public static class workerThread implements Runnable {
    LinkedList<Integer> ll_only_for_read;
    PrintWriter writer;
    public workerThread(LinkedList<Integer> ll,int id2) throws Exception {
        ll_only_for_read = ll;
        writer = new PrintWriter("file."+id2, "UTF-8");
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(Integer i : ll_only_for_read) writer.println(" ll:"+i);
        writer.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<1e3;i++) ll.add(i);
    // do I need to call something special here? (in order to say:
    // "hey LinkeList flush all your data from local cache
    // you will be now a good boy and share those data among
    // whole lot of interesting threads. Don't worry though they will only read
    // you, no thread would dare to change you"
    new Thread(new workerThread(ll,1)).start();
    new Thread(new workerThread(ll,2)).start();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in your specific example code it's okay, since the act of creating the new thread should define a happens-before relationship between populating the list and reading it from another thread."  There are plenty of ways that a seemingly-similar set up could be unsafe, however.

I highly recommend reading "Java Concurrency in Practice" by Brian Goetz et al for more details.

Comment: Still didn't have a time to read a book but here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility is a short paragraph "Memory Consistency Properties" which lists what operations guarantees "happens-before" term.

Answer (score 2):

If your code created and populated the list with a single thread and only in a second moment you create other threads that concurrently access the list there is no problem.

Only when a thread can modify a value while other threads try to read the same value can happens problems.

It can be a problem if you change the object you retrieve (also if you don't change the list itself).

Answer (score 2):

> Although one answer was warning about "unflushed cache" and advicing to know "java memory model".

I think you are referring to my Answer to this Question: [Can Java LinkedList be read in multiple-threads safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659977/can-java-linkedlist-be-read-in-multiple-threads-safely/11660017?noredirect=1#comment46230167_11660017).

> So I'm asking to elaborate those "evil" caches.

They are not evil.  They are just a fact of life ... and they affect the correctness (thread-safety) reasoning for multi-threaded applications.

The Java Memory Model is Java's answer to this fact of life.  The memory model specifies with mathematical precision a bunch of rules that need to be obeyed to ensure that all possible executions of your application are "well-formed".  (In simple terms: that your application is thread-safe.)

The Java Memory Model is ... difficult.

Someone recommended "Java Concurrency in Practice" by Brian Goetz et al.  I concur.  It is the best textbook on the topic of writing "classic" Java multi-threaded applications, and it has a good explanation of the Java Memory Model.

More importantly, Goetz et al gives you a *simpler* set of rules that are *sufficient* to give you thread-safety.  These rules are still too detailed to condense into StackOverflow answer ... but

- one of the concepts is "safe publication", and
- one of the principles is to use / re-use existing concurrency constructs rather than to roll your own concurrency mechanisms based on the Memory Model.

> I'm a newbie and so far I still naively believe that following code is ok.

It >>is<< correct.  However ...

> (at least from my tests)

... testing is NOT a guarantee of anything.  The problem with non-thread-safe programs is that the faults are frequently not revealed by testing because they manifest randomly, with low probability, and often differently on different platforms.

You cannot rely on testing to tell you that your code is thread-safe.  You need to reason<sup>1</sup> about the behaviour ... or follow a set of well-founded rules.

---

<sup>1 - And I mean real, well-founded reasoning ... not seat-of-the-pants intuitive stuff.</sup>

Comment: thanks for replying. Although mostly I understand only that it's a difficult :) Thx for recommending the book I'll add it to my todo reading list. Also thx for approving my solution from Java Memory Model and Caches view... I'm glad I got it intuitively right so far..

Comment: Yes ... but a small change would make it unsafe.  Unless you *really* understand the Java Memory Model, your intuition is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're using it is fine, but only by coincidence.

Programs are rarely that trivial:

- If the List contains references to other (mutable) data, then you'll get race conditions.
- If someone modifies your 'reader' threads later in the code's lifecycle, then you'll get races.

Immutable data (and data structures) are by definition thread-safe.  *However*, this is a mutable List, even though you're making the agreement with yourself that you won't modify it.

I'd recommend wrapping the `List<>` instance like this so the code fails immediately if someone tries to use any mutators on the List:

`List<Integer> immutableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(ll);
//...pass 'immutableList' to threads.`

Link to [unmodifiableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List))

Comment: The data structure he's using is not immutable. And creating immutable views for consumers won't prevent modification by anyone that retains a reference to the underlying collection.

Comment: Fair point; edited to reflect.  Providing an unmodifiable view may be appropriate, depending upon his usecase.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the object was created and made available to your thread. In general, no, it's not safe, even if the object isn't modified.

Following are some ways to make it safe.

First, create the object and perform any modification that is necessary; you can consider the object to be *effectively immutable* if no more modifications occur. Then, share the effectively immutable object with other threads by one of the following means:

- Have other threads read the object from a field that is `volatile`.
- Write a reference to the object inside a `synchronized` block, then have other threads read that reference while `synchronized` on the same lock.
- Start the reading threads after the object is initialized, passing the object as a parameter. (This is what you are doing in your example, so you are safe.)
- Pass the object between threads using a concurrent mechanism like a `BlockingQueue` implementation, or publish it in a concurrent collection, like a `ConcurrentMap` implementation.

There might be others. Alternatively, you can make all of the fields of the shared object `final` (including all the fields of its `Object` members, and so on). Then it will be safe to share this object by any means across threads. That's one of the under-appreciated virtues of immutable types.

Comment: He asked for particular use case. And his use case is fine. All the recommendations you made are not necessary in his case. There is no point of guarding code against event that are not relevant to it.

Comment: @Zielu Did you read the title of the question? It's not specific at all. Read the entire question. He wants "elaboration" about the visibility of data in the face of "caching."

Comment: I read, and he asks about his believe that the following code is ok. And he asks about access using only read operations not about mixing them with writes.

Comment: The question itself, as well as the context of the question with respect to the previous answer to which it refers, make it abundantly clear that his question is more general. Where does he ask for a particular use case? He provides one example of a general principle.

Comment: Sorry for arguing with much more experienced users, but you still may want  to edit your answer. You are wrongly suggest that making  the list variable final/volatile (I dont know if semantic of your bullet points is or/and) provides the thread safety.

Comment: @Zielu After re-reading the specification on `final` field initialization, it's not clear to me that publishing the object in a `final` field would transitively ensure visibility of its non-final members. Publishing through a `volatile` field does ensure visibility in this way. So I removed the point about `final`, but the point about `volatile` stands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to guarantee happens-before relationship between reads and writes in your LinkedList because they are done in separate threads.

Result of `ll.add(i)` will be visible for new workerThread because `Thread.start` forms happens-before relationship. So your example is thread safe. See more about [happens-before conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility).

However be aware of more complex situation, when LinkedList is read during iteration in worker threads and at the same time it is modified by the main thread. Like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<1e3;i++) {
    ll.add(i);
    new Thread(new workerThread(ll,1)).start();
    new Thread(new workerThread(ll,2)).start();
}
```

This way ConcurrentModificationException is possible.

There are several options:

1. Clone your LinkedList inside of workerThread and iterate the copy
   instead.
2. Use synchronization both for list modification and for list
   iteration (but it will lead to poor concurrency).
3. Instead of LinkedList use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering to my question. But I was thinking of your reassuring answers and I found it may not be so safe as it seems. I found and tested case when it is not working - if object would use it's class variable for storing any data (I wouldn't know about) then it would fail (then the only question is if linked list (and other java classes) in some implementation can do it...) See failing example:

```
public class DummyLinkedList {
    public LinkedList<Integer> ll;
    public DummyLinkedList(){
        ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
    int lastGetIndex;
    int myDummyGet(int idx){
        lastGetIndex = idx;
        //return ll.get(idx); // thids would work fine as parameter is on the stack so uniq for each call (at least if java supports reentrant functions)
        return ll.get(lastGetIndex); // this would make a problem even for only readin the object - question is how many such issues java.* contains
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a thread-safety issue at all.  This (the failing example) is simply a bug.

Comment: I do not understand why it is a bug? I agree in such a short code it is stupidly written - it was for demonstrative purposes. But imagine there is something useful - like imagine it would store internally lastly accessed index+value in order to speed up response. In such case you should not call it a bug and I would not call it a stupidly written code. Also it works fine for single thread or when wrapped into "synchronized".

Comment: OK maybe that was overstating it.  As currently written, the bug can only manifest itself if there are multiple threads.  But it the problem is that you are using field as a local variable which makes the code non-reentrant.  In similar cases, doing this would break a single-threaded application; e.g. if `myDummyGet` was recursive.  And besides, this does not meet the criteria of your question. The assignment to `lastGetIndex` is a modification of the state of the object.  You question is about thread-safety if there aren't any modifications.

Comment: Yup I agree - not recursive-able. But the point is I do not know implementation of library functions. Is there way to be sure that calling seemingly read only function like get() does not modify something inside??? (like remembering last accessed value). Is there some annotation for that like @NotModifyingObject? If there is not such a thing that I think it is relevant and in scope of my question. And we would have to use some lock()/semaphore()/synchronized() every time we are using seemingly only read function as we can not be sure of implementation. Right?

Comment: That is right.  Unless the library method or class is documented as being thread-safe, (or you have analysed it), then you should assume that it isn't and synchronize.

Answer (score -2):

If you only access to the list is by 'read' methods (including iterations) then you are fine. Like in your code.

Comment: There's a lot more to it than that. Read-only access isn't guaranteed to "work". Read about "safe publication."

Comment: Could you prove me wrong please. I honestly don't see how reading a variable could not be thread safe.

Comment: the safe publication is not relevant here. the access happens after the creation and write operations.

Comment: It is relevant. His (accidental) safe publication by starting threads after modification of the object is what makes his code work. If that's what you are pointing to in defending your answer, *you should have mentioned it your answer.*

Comment: I don't believe user who cites "It seems the answer is yes as far as no-one structurally changes it (add/delete) from the linked list.", "accidentally" writes to the list before trying to read from it. But I don't need to defend my answer more, I can really live with that loss of the reputation.